# How to use fixed background in Ionic?

Tags: css, scroll, ionic-framework

Having issues with making fixed background in Ionic

Here is my code:

```
  <ion-scroll direction="y" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 49px);">
    <div style="width: 100%; background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url('{{profile.photo}}') no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;">
      <h3 style="color: #fff; padding-top: 70%; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 10px;">{{profile.name}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="reset_this">
      <div class="spacer" style="width: 300px; height: 2000px;"></div>
    </div>
  </ion-scroll>
```

I think that Ionic's styles override something, cause when I remove ionic.css everything works perfectly. Also, I tried to disable native scrolling and it didn't help.